# Spring Boot changing property-source order by overriding StandardServletEnvironment - bad idea?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot uses a PropertySource order that is designed to allow sensible overriding of values, properties are considered in the following order:

1. Devtools global settings properties on your home directory (~/.spring-boot-devtools.properties when devtools is active).
2. @TestPropertySource annotations on your tests.
3. @SpringBootTest#properties annotation attribute on your tests.
4. Command line arguments.
5. Properties from SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON (inline JSON embedded in an environment variable or system property).
6. ServletConfig init parameters.
7. ServletContext init parameters.
8. JNDI attributes from java:comp/env.
9. Java System properties (System.getProperties()).
10. OS environment variables.
11. A RandomValuePropertySource that has properties only in random.*.
12. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
13. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
14. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
15. Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
16. @PropertySource annotations on your @Configuration classes.
17. Default properties (specified by setting SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties).

I am wondering why servlet context/config are ranked higher than runtime properties / environment?  Doesn't this make it impossible to override hard coded context/config in the web.xml (or annotations)?

Background: We are trying to add spring boot to a historic project where we have previously had the opposite behavior.

I have figured out how to change the order by overriding the StandardServletEnvironment#customizePropertySources(...) and putting:

- system properties
- system environment
- servlet config
- servlet context

What would be the ramifications of doing this? Is there a hidden pitfall?

Answer (score 0):

Well of course as soon as I post, I *think* I found the answer to my own question.

*If* I understand correctly, the above is the *loading order*.

But the important detail I was probably missing was the following from the documentation:

> When resolving properties (i.e. @Value("${myprop}") resolving is done
> in the reverse order.

In this case, the lookup order would be as I intended without changing the property-source order.